# minicom on /dev/tty# - Ctl-A Z doesn't appear to work?

Tags: console, minicom

I have an old laptop (Dell Latitude D610) that I want to use as a serial terminal for some systems that require that, since this machine has a built-in RS-232 port. I have installed Debian 12 and minicom, but without graphical environment, so I login on the text console. However when I start minicom, `Ctl-A Z` doesn't open the help menu - instead I just see `z` echoed and the cursor doesn't move. In fact I have observed the same in screen, so this isn't limited to minicom.

On my new laptop, I see the same phenomenon, but it works without problems in a GUI terminal on the same system, so it seems to be specific to the text mode consoles. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change to fix this issue?

Comment: After `Ctrl-A`, are you pressing the unshifted `z` key, or the shifted `Z` key?  The tutorials I've seen suggest the latter is what brings up the help screen.

Comment: @SottoVoce Interesting - I'll try that now. Actually, that worked; I've never had to do that before, so I'm surprised. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minicom help screen key binding is `Ctrl-A Z` with an uppercase `Z`. The symptoms you describe are consistent with pressing the keys `Ctrl-A z` with a lowercase/unshifted `z`.

`screen` uses `Ctrl-A z` to exit from a session while leaving the session running, which is a common thing to do.  Perhaps your muscle memory has been remembering the `screen` keystroke sequence while you're using `minicom`.

Comment: Still `Ctrl-A` is really `Ctrl+a` (lowercase/unshifted). This adds to the confusion.